# IDENTITY_INSERT ON error with foreign key

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to set Id manually for some entries.

I have a Customer class with an Identity field

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().Property(f => f.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
```

and in the insert part I have

```
    using (var transaction = ctx.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
      ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Customers] ON");
      ctx.Customers.AddRange(customersList);
      ctx.SaveChanges();
      ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Customers] OFF");
      transaction.Commit();
    }
```

but I'm still getting the exception

> Explicit value must be specified for identity column in table
>   'Customers' either when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to ON or when a
>   replication user is inserting into a NOT FOR REPLICATION identity
>   column.

In the StateEntries of my exception, I can see that all the fields that are stored in another table like "Contacts" seems to be the cause
`customer.Contacts = new List<Contact> {new Contact {Name = "Test", … }}`

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That error message is misleading.  You are succeeding in turning IDENTITY_INSERT on, but EF is still generating an INSERT statement under the assumption that the key value will be generated by the IDENTITY column.

So you *additionally* must generate an INSERT statement containing the key value.  You can, of course, use .ExecuteSqlCommand() to perform the INSERT as well.  Or you can get EF to do it, but you must use a model where that Entity does not have database-generated keys.  OnModelCreating configures the model only once per ModelType, so you can't just put a switch in there.

Instead you can create a subtype of your DbContext for seeding, overriding the entity configuration of the base DbContext.  Like this:

```
class Db_Seed: Db
{
    public Db_Seed(string constr) : base(constr)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<Db_Seed>(null);  //no initializer
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().Property(c => c.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
    }
}
```

You *still* must set IDENTITY_INSERT on (since the table does have an IDENTITY), but with this context EF will not generate an INSERT statement that assumes the server will generate the key.

Comment: thanks you very much. it's working and your explanation is very good.